# How to bind port 80 for my tomcat 7 on centos 7

Tags: tomcat7, centos7

log:

```
Dec 05, 2015 2:22:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-80]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-80]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:813)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:980)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Permission denied <null>:80
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:411)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:640)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Permission denied
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:181)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:49)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:398)
        ... 17 more
```

And I followed the instruction [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-7-on-centos-7-via-yum) to install tomcat.

It seams that I should grant permissions to my tomcat but how?  And when I googled this problem, many says that I should modify this file `/etc/defaults/tomcat7` But, I do not have this file on my centOS 7.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Or can anybody just tell me how to run my tomcat as root. I

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by forwarding:

`firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-forward-port=port=80:proto=tcp:toport=8080 --permanent`

and

`firewall-cmd --reload`